# How to filter the dictionary by the list correctly

Tags: python, list, dictionary

There is a dictionary and a list of dictionaries. It is necessary to filter the dictionary by key, excluding duplicate values that are in the list (name).

```
dict1 = {'code': 'varchar(25)', 'cnt': 'int', 'id': 'int'}

lst1 = [{'name': 'client', 'datatype': 'varchar(100)'}, {'name': 'id', 'datatype': 'int'}, {'name': 'status', 'datatype': 'varchar(10)'}]
```

Return:

```
dict2 = {'code': 'varchar(25)', 'cnt': 'int'}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a set of the `name`s from `lst1`:

```
>>> names = {d['name'] for d in lst1}
>>> names
{'id', 'client', 'status'}
```

and then make a dict that excludes keys that are in that set:

```
>>> {k: v for k, v in dict1.items() if k not in names}
{'code': 'varchar(25)', 'cnt': 'int'}
```